# How can I share a plotly-dash with my colleagues?

Tags: plotly-dash

There is a way to share it with my team for free? or I need to pay for it? If I need to pay, with platform you recommend besides the dash enterprise?

I tried on Heroku and others platforms, but unsuccessfully. There is other way to do it for free?

There anyone that can help me with it? Thank you!!